# How to accumulate a DataFrame in RxPy?

Tags: python, rx-py

I'm simulating a calculation over a number of inputs which take a long while. Whenever a calculation is done (i.e. `on_next` is emitted), I hope to reactively append the result to a results data frame and print the final DF when `on_completed` is emitted. However, the DF is empty, why are no values accumulating?

This is with Python 3.9.9 and rxpy 3.2.0.

```
import time
from random import random, randint
from rx import create
import pandas as pd
import rx
print(rx.__version__)

def accumulate(result, i):
    # Here the values should accumulate !?
    result = result.append(pd.DataFrame({'a': [i]}))

def average_df(observer, scheduler):
    for pid in pids:
        time.sleep(random()*0.8)
        observer.on_next(randint(0, 100))
    observer.on_completed()

def print_result(result):
    print(result)

# Client
if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = pd.DataFrame({'a': []})

    # Observable
    pids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    source = create(average_df)
    
    source.subscribe(
        on_next = lambda i: accumulate(result, i),
        on_error = lambda e: print("Error: {0}".format(e)),
        on_completed = lambda: print_result(result)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The pandas append function returns a new object. In accumulate, this new object is set to the local variable *result*. This does not update the *result* variable that is in the main block.

You can get the final dataframe by returning the accumulated values at each step, thanks to the [scan](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_operators.html?highlight=scan#rx.operators.scan) operator:

```
import time
from random import random, randint
import rx
import rx.operators as ops
import pandas as pd
import rx
print(rx.__version__)

def accumulate():
    def _accumulate(acc, I):
        return acc.append(pd.DataFrame({'a': [i]}))

    return  ops.scan(_accumulate, seed=pd.DataFrame({'a': []}))

def average_df(observer, scheduler):
    for pid in pids:
        time.sleep(random()*0.8)
        observer.on_next(randint(0, 100))
    observer.on_completed()


# Client
if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = pd.DataFrame({'a': []})

    # Observable
    pids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    source = rx.create(average_df)

    df = source.pipe(
        accumulate(),
        ops.last(),
    ).run()
print(df)
```

Also for more simplifications, you can use the [to_pandas](https://www.makinage.org/doc/rxsci/latest/operators_other.html?highlight=to_pandas#rxsci.ops.to_pandas) operators of the [rxsci](https://github.com/maki-nage/rxsci/) library (disclaimer, I am the author). Here is a solution with rxsci, and a more reactive way to create the source observable:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import time
from random import random, randint
import rx
import rx.operators as ops
import pandas as pd
import rxsci as rs
print(rx.__version__)


class Item(NamedTuple):
    pid: int
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = pd.DataFrame({'a': []})

    # Observable
    pids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    source = rx.from_(pids).pipe(
        ops.do_action(lambda i: time.sleep(random()*0.8)),
        ops.map(lambda i: Item(pid=randint(0, 100))),
    )
    
    df = source.pipe(
        rs.ops.to_pandas(),
    ).run()
    
print(df)
```